# Jackson Date Format from HashMap

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a problem with jackson outputting my date in the below format.

```
    {"DOB":1173196800000}
```

However, I want it to be something more readable. I have seen solutions using the jsonDateSerializer and Deserializer class and has some success in using it for POJO related implementation.

[How to deserialize JS date using Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591967/jackson-date-deserialization)

The problem I am facing right now would be the mapping of sql objects to a hashmap instead of a POJO. I am unclear where I could specify the object mapping part for hashmap

```
    public @ResponseBody ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> sqlObjectRetrieval(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> retrievedObjects = 
        objectFromSql.retrieved(1,2,3);
    }
```

I am using Spring3 and jackson for this implementation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
                    <property name="dateFormat">
                        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                            <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

in your spring-mvc.xml

Comment: Thanks the solution works. However, I am still unclear of the stuff it is doing? would you be able to provide more explanation? How is Spring able to map the date attribute to this date format?

Comment: Spring MVC use MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to Convert returned data to JSON format. In fact, Jackson2 ObjectMapper class to the serialization. If you need to config more detail json format, you should config ObjectMapper in Spring-MVC.xml or annotation in Entity java beans. For more information, read the jackson document.