# Jackson 2.3.2: Issue with deserializing a Date despite of setting the date format to ObjectMapper

Tags: json, datetime, deserialization, resteasy

I am using rest easy and want to serialize and deserialize dates.

After creating my json provider, Serializing is working fine but deserializing is still not working.

My JsonProvider class:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

   public JsonProvider() {

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
      mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
      mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
      mapper.setDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

      super.setMapper(mapper);
   }
}
```

**Input date**: 09 Sep, 2014 11:00:00 AM

**Error:**
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '09 Sep, 2014 11:00:00 AM': **not a valid representation** (error: Failed to parse Date value '09 Sep, 2014 11:00:00 AM': **Can not parse date "09 Sep, 2014 11:00:00 AM"**: not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591967/jackson-date-deserialization) workaround but if I use this then I have to annotate every date field in my app which I feel is an overhead.

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, this solved my problem

`mapper.setDateFormat(myDateFormat)`

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling