# JsonFormat annotation to parse two date type

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jackson, fasterxml

I have a problem, I want to parse to different type of date string to timestamp.

I used

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern ="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS       z",timezone="IST")
private Timestamp validUptoDate;
```

and parsing is Ok when milisecond value is given after second, But if I provide `"16-DEC-2014 15:20:30 IST"` this type of date, getting below exception ::

```
Failed to parse Date value '15-AUG-2019 19:30:00 IST' (format: "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z"): Unparseable date: "15-AUG-2019 19:30:00 IST"
```

But If I provide  `"16-DEC-2014 15:20:30.000 IST"` , then no issues. But I dont want to mention milisecond value if not present.

I tried to provide two pattern value llike

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern ={"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z","dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z"} ,timezone="IST")
```

but compilation error happens.
I tried using different combination, but no hope. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried removing .SSS part from HH:mm:ss.SSS ? @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern ="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z",timezone="IST")

Comment: yes, it worked when I removed .SSS part. But I want to parse two type of pattern simultaneously, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: By looking at the javadoc pattern only accepts "string" values not array like you provided. But it does not say anything about regular expressions. Try something like pattern="pattern1|pattern2" and we will know if it accepts regex values.

Comment: i tried using pattern="pattern1|pattern2", but no improve ! :(

Comment: Got 1 useful link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591967/jackson-date-deserialization

Comment: By reading that link I guess you can solve it by creating a custom object mapper and setting default date format to ISO8601DateFormat(). If you don't know how to do that I can provide more details as answer.

Comment: also got another link for customised serialization :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson