# Spring Json parse date

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have an angular app which send me a date like this dd/MM/yyyy and like this yyyy-MM-dd. 
How can i use @JsonFormat to accept two kind of pattern?
Currently i just use:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date hireDate;
```

it's work when the date that i receive is in this format dd/MM/yyyyy but when  the date is in this format yyyy-MM-dd i have a json parse error

```
 org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2018-10-26": expected format "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Answer (score 1):

The json format accepts a single argument. You can use regex instead or a custom deserializer.

**Pattern:**

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(pattern="^(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})|^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})"
private Date hireDate;
```

**Custom deserializer**:(https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598277)

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class)
```

P.S: Please note that the regex pattern I gave doesn't cover the date validation of wrong months or wrong number of days. Thus I advice to use custom deserializer or ask the caller to send in UTC timestamp format.